# Is it possible to develop iOS apps with xcodebuild and entirely without Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcodebuild

I've been able to build and run iOS apps with `xcodebuild` and `ios-deploy`, but I still have to create files and renaming files in Xcode, otherwise xcodebuild won't notice my changes. Is there a way to do these without xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with https://fastlane.tools/ with action gym

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know fastlane provides tools for building, I'll check that out